# Obj-C - Google Maps SDK get data for selected marker?

Tags: objective-c, gmsmapview

I'm trying to get the data for a selected marker using the following code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

 NSMutableDictionary *viewParams3 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
     [viewParams3 setValue:@"breweries" forKey:@"view_name"];
     [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams3 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         
         self.breweryLocations = [responseObject mutableCopy];
      
      
         int index = 0;
         
         for (NSMutableDictionary *brewInfo in self.breweryLocations) {
         
         NSString *location = brewInfo[@"address"];
         NSString *userNames = brewInfo[@"node_title"];
         NSString *firstRemoved = [userNames stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#039;" withString:@""];

          
         NSString *userBio = brewInfo[@"body"];
         

          
          CLGeocoder *geocoderFriend = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
          [geocoderFriend geocodeAddressString:location
            completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
            if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
           CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
             MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
      
                
                
                CLLocationCoordinate2D position = placemark.coordinate;
                GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
                marker.title = firstRemoved;
                marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"brewIconMax"];
                marker.map = self.mapView;
                marker.userData = self.breweryLocations;
               
                marker.map.selectedMarker.zIndex = index + 1;
                                                                               }
          
          }
                                                        ];
          
          }
      
         
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }];


}

- (BOOL) mapView: (GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{

   self.venueCategory.text = marker.userData[mapView.selectedMarker.zIndex][@"type"];

}
```

That said, this line of code

```
self.venueCategory.text = marker.userData[mapView.selectedMarker.zIndex][@"type"];
```

returns the data from the first dictionary in my array no matter which marker I tap (zIndex is always returned as 0). I can't seem to find the correct code to obtain the selected marker's array data anywhere.

Any idea what that line should look like instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether "type" is an element of the brewery location dictionary, so I'm taking some guesses here.

I'd suggest setting `marker.userData` to the `brewInfo` dictionary, and not the entire `breweryLocations` array.

```
marker.userData = brewInfo;
```

Then this to get the "type" from the `brewInfo` dictionary.

```
self.venueCategory.text = marker.userData[@"type"];
```

Comment: Ahh this did the trick - thank you SO much!!

Comment: how could I not help with the cute dog photo ;-)

Comment: Lol! Glad including my dog in my photo is enticing the masses to answer my questions, ha ha. Thanks a million :)